# Custom HeaderTitle in createMaterialTopTabNavigator within StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following router set up with use of `React-Navigation`:

```js
const MainView = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    DrawerMain: {
      screen: StackNavScreens,
    },
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    contentComponent: Settings,
  },
);

const StackNavScreens = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: TabNav,
    },
    Screen1: {
      screen: Screen1,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'Screen1 Title',
      },
    },
    Screen2: {
      screen: Screen2,
    },
    },
    {
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      headerTitle: <Image source="Logo" />,
})
}}

const TabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Tab1: {
      screen: Tab1Screen,
    },
    Tab2: {
      screen: Tab2Screen,
    },
    Tab3: {
      screen: Tab3Screen,
    },
  },{});
```

I have setup the headerTitle in the stack navigator, so that it works in the following way: if user is on `Screen1`, the navigation title will be shown as `Screen1 Title`. If he goes to `Screen2`, he will see logo (`<Image source="Logo"/>`). However, I am having hard time intercepting the header title for the `Tab1`, `Tab2` and `Tab3`. I've tried passing `headerTitle` in `navigationOptions` for each of the Tabs - but it didn't had any effect. Right now, all the tabs display default `headerTitle` from `StackNavigator` - the logo.

Any suggestions on how can I set the header title for the tabs in described scenario?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? i have the same problem

Comment: I also have this problem

Answer (score 2):

I created a createStackNavigator wrap the createMaterialTopTabar, and config header for this createStackNavigator. It working well.

```js
const WatchTopTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  VideoScreen: {
    screen: VideoStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Video',
      tabBarIcon: ({
        tintColor
      }) => ( <
        Image source = {
          require('../assets/images/video.png')
        } //eslint-disable-line
        style = {
          {
            tintColor,
            width: 24,
            height: 24
          }
        }
        />
      )
    }
  },
  PhotoScreen: {
    screen: Photo,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Ảnh',
      tabBarIcon: ({
        tintColor
      }) => ( <
        Image source = {
          require('../assets/images/video.png')
        } //eslint-disable-line
        style = {
          {
            tintColor,
            width: 24,
            height: 24
          }
        }
        />
      )
    }
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    tabStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    style: {

    },
    labelStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
});

const WatchRoute = createStackNavigator({
  watchTopTabNavigator: WatchTopTabNavigator
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTitle: < Header / >
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and after read this issue https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/741 from Github I found solution. You are close, just add `navigationOptions` inside `Main` object on your `StackNavScreen`

```
const StackNavScreens = createStackNavigator(
{
    Main: {
        screen: TabNav,
        navigationOptions: { headerTitle: 'Header title' },
    },
}
```

I hope you were luck and found this answer help you, cheer!